# Can't apply proper format to a pandas dateframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a code for date interpretation that goes like this:
`data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'], unit='ms')`

The results, however, vary in the format. Some are like this: `2017-08-17 04:00:00.000`, and others are like that: `2020-05-05 20:00:00`. Is there a way to remove the miliseconds? I've tried with the format kwarg, but pandas doesn't allow both unit and format in the same line. I've tried messing with the replace function, but only got errors. So is there a way to remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
data['timestamp'] =  data['timestamp'].astype('datetime64[s]')
```

Comment: I get this error then: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: Please post part of your dataframe here so I can do a run on it

Comment: This is the whole set (it's very long): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ILERk7yHrdNlj4t9v5M0L_y1w_4opDi4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Still didn't work. Recent data is: 2020-05-07 00:00:00, while the start still is 2017-08-17 04:00:00.000.

Comment: Just to note, I'm placing the `data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'], format ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', errors='ignore')` right after `data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'], unit='ms')`, since I can't alter both the unit and the format in the same line.

Comment: Why do you need the second line of code for?
I could not find in the link to the CSV you sent any data like  2020-05-07 00:00:00. which line is it?

Comment: That is because the csv file is generated with the ETHUSDT price on Binance. The  2020-05-07 didn't appear in the file because it was generated in 2020-05-05.

Comment: This is the original code: `klines = binance_client.get_historical_klines(symbol, kline_size, oldest_point.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"),
                                                  newest_point.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"))
    data = pd.DataFrame(klines,
                        columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'close_time', 'quote_av',
                                 'trades', 'tb_base_av', 'tb_quote_av', 'ignore'])
    data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'], unit='ms')`

Comment: The problem is: the data starts with XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:00.000 and ends with XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:00, which is why I want it formated to remove the microseconds.

Comment: Now I see your problem. I have updated my answer above. It should work. Let me know

Comment: Now it's working! Thank you so much for the help, and sorry if I wasn't precise.

Comment: That's ok. Glad I helped